# Plotting a list with variable(chemical formula, number)

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, formatting, charts, text

I have a list like this
List=((co2-Teo2,12),(Al2o3,15),(Ta2O5,16));
I want to plot the list so that the x axis I have the right format of chemical formula and have chemical formula in my plot legends.
I am a starter please guide me

Comment: Hello. Even if you are new to Mathematica, you must explain clearly what you want. For example, draw a picture of what you want and include it in your question (you can edit your question if you do not know that yet). Perhaps `BarChart[{3,4,2},ChartLabels->{"a","b","c"}]` is the kind of thing you want?

Comment: `alist = {{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(CO\), \
\(2\)]\)-\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(TeO\), \(2\)]\)", 
    12}, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Al\), \
\(2\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(O\), \(3\)]\)", 
    15}, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Ta\), \
\(2\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(O\), \(5\)]\)", 16}};
BarChart[Last /@ alist, ChartLabels -> First /@ alist, 
 ChartLegends -> First /@ alist, ChartStyle -> "Pastel"]`